# Azure ADO Helminstaller Unable to locate executable file: 'helm'

Tags: azure-devops

I am using helm installer task in  ado yaml pipeline. It  has been working fine for more than a year now. All of a sudden today I am seeing below error.

```
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'helm'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

My yaml file:

```
     - task: HelmInstaller@0
        inputs:
          helmVersion: ${{ parameters.helmVersion }}
          installKubectl: true
          checkLatestHelmVersion: false
```

Did anyone face this issue ?

Further logs from the task:

```
Downloading: https://api.github.com/repos/helm/helm/releases
(node:144) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
Downloading: https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.10.2-linux-amd64.zip
Extracting archive
/usr/bin/unzip /__w/_temp/helm-v3.10.2-f8239f1e-9c15-41c1-b7db-776e2cbaa057.zip
Archive:  /__w/_temp/helm-v3.10.2-f8239f1e-9c15-41c1-b7db-776e2cbaa057.zip
   creating: linux-amd64/
  inflating: linux-amd64/helm
  inflating: linux-amd64/LICENSE
  inflating: linux-amd64/README.md
Caching tool: helm 3.10.2 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /__t/helm/3.10.2/x64/linux-amd64
Verifying helm installation...
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'helm'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
Finishing: HelmInstaller
```

Comment: Observing the same issue with `DockerInstaller@0` but in this case there isn't a `DockerInstaller@1` (yet) which would fix the problem. Perhaps there is a general bug in Azure task's tarball extraction logic?

Comment: Related [upstream issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17352).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem.  We are running our pipeline on our own agent, so was able to confirm that the helm files are downloaded correctly.  The issue seems to be that the file is not set as executable.

I have raised an issue on MS developer community (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Helm-tool-installer-recently-started-fai/10221504?space=21&sort=newest) and will update any feedback I receive.

As a workaround, I have found that using the HelmInstaller@1 (along with KubectlInstaller@0 where necessary) has allowed me to get my pipeline working again.

Comment: Using `@1` is recommended anyway. Not sure why things broke though.

Answer (score 1):

We've had the same issue today morning and we fixed using HelmInstaller@1 Preview and also we needed to add a new task for Kubectl Tool Installer.

With that our pipelines were fixed.